# Cron job is not working for random some days

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, cron

I've used the cron [npm package](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron#readme) and have passed time string "59 59 03 * * *". So, it is run on every days at 5:30 AM (America Los Angeles time), but for some days it's not working and mostly they are Sunday & Monday.

```
import {CronJob} from 'cron';

const updateSelfStorageFacilityJob = new CronJob({
  cronTime: '59 59 03 * * *', 
  onTick: Meteor.bindEnvironment(function() {
    console.log('<==============start periodic job update self storage facility===============>')
  }),
  onComplete: function () {
    console.log('<=====complete periodic job update self storage facility=====>');
  },
  start: false,
  timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles'
});

updateSelfStorageFacilityJob.start();
```

Comment: Does the server do any automatic package updates,  something that might trigger a reboot, or anything else that might cause the cron service to be unavailable?

Comment: I don't think so because that is only happening in weekends when our server does not serve any request (means in ideal condition) because we have only 2 users and they are not using it at the weekends.

Comment: Which also means it would be the ideal time for _automatic_ updates & reboots

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll check but I don't think it's a root cause of the issue.

Comment: Yeah, I wish I had an answer for you. That is the first thing I would check though before trying to debug someone else's package

Comment: maybe try this package instead : https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-synced-cron works like a charm for me.